# I want to know how to "fill" the TStings defined in CollectLangString?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

What is the "engine" under TLang...

TLang is ok in my small project but with larger project It is difficult to manage. I try to figure how it works. I've fund many proc and functions in FMX.Types. I've focus on: CollectLangStart, CollectLangFinish and CollectLangStrings. Calling those function can be compiled but I don't know where and when this TStrings is filled, the TStrings stay empty. The documentation talk about "scene" but it is very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TStyleManager.UpdateScenes` must be called between `CollectLangStart` and copying `CollectLangStrings`

```
var
  Str: TStrings;
begin
  CollectLangStart;
  TStyleManager.UpdateScenes;
  Str := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Str.Assign(CollectLangStrings); 
    Str.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'lang.lng');
  finally   
    Str.Free;
    CollectLangFinish;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `CollectLangStart/Finish` and `TStringList.Create/Free` should be in separate `try/finally` blocks.

Comment: @Remy: indeed. So `CollectLangStart; try ... Str := TStringList.Create; try ... finally Str.Free; end; finally CollectLangFinish; end;` or probably even the other way around.

Comment: I would create the `TStringList` first, then collect and release the lang strings, then save and free the `TStringList`. That way the lang memory has been freed before `SaveToFile()` needs to allocate any memory of its own.

Comment: @Remy: that is what I meant with "even the other way around".